# How do I capture repeat values with .NET regex?

Tags: .net, regex

Lets say I want to capture the words

My Regex

```
(\w+) (n\d+)(,\s*(n\d+))*
```

My input

```
Word1 n0, n1, n2, n99
```

1 will get me `Word1` 2 will get me `n0` 4 will get me `n99`. Is there a way I can get n1 and n2???

Comment: 4 what gets you `n99`? I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @JimMischel: The 4th capture group. In .NET i'd write matchobj.Group[4].value. 0 is always the full line. Javascript does the same.

Comment: Please show the code you use to get these results.

Comment: What he means is that, because he has a quantifier on the third capture group, the inner capture only captures the last instance of the quantified expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck! There is, and AFAIK, only in .NET! See [the MSDN documentation, here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection.aspx).

> If a quantifier is applied to a capturing group, the CaptureCollection includes one Capture object for each captured substring, and the Group object provides information only about the last captured substring.

Basically, you iterate through the `CaptureCollection` member. The example on that page is pretty informative.